# Rest service with multiple parameter

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-core

I have a service where I am searching for a user.

and my service URL is http://localhost:5000/SearchStudent/Name

```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("api/[controller]/SearchStudent")]
    public SearchResult SearchStudent(string name)
    {

       SearchResult result = Search(Name);
     }
```

Now I have to change my URL like below

http://localhost:5000/School1/SearchStudent

http://localhost:5000/School2/SearchStudent

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/[controller]/School/SearchStudent")]
public SearchResult SearchStudent(string name)
{
    if(school1)
      SearchResult result = Search(Name)
    else if (school2)
      SearchResult result = Search1(Name)
 }
```

Any idea on how to implement this

Comment: Your given urls did not match to the declared routes. Please fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional parameter in your route

```cs
[HttpGet("/search/{schoolName}/{studentId}")]
public string Search(string schoolName, string studentId)
{
    return $"{schoolName} -> {studentId}";
}
```

More info about "[Routing to controller actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)"